# How does this work? {now:%Y/%m/%Y%m%d%H%M%S}{ext}"

Tags: python, django

I am reading Django Cookbook 2 and I came across an image upload form that doesn't work as expected. When the user uploads an image it names the image as the date and time at that moment in time.

What I can't figure out is when the form saves, it doesn't actually render to have numbers in it and stays with the %Y/%m characters.

> return f"profile/{now:%Y/%m/%Y%m%d%H%M%S}{ext}"

Secondly, why is there an "f", because it keeps throwing an error if I don't remove it.

**Views.py**

```
from django.utils.timezome inport now as timezone_now

def upload_to(instance, filename):
    now = timezone_now()
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    ext = ext.lower()
    return f"profile/{now:%Y/%m/%Y%m%d%H%M%S}{ext}"
```

Comment: If the "f" produces an error, then you don't have a recent enough version of Python to run this code.  That's a *f-string* - a new way of inserting variable values into strings, that's more compact than the previous `.format()` or `%` techniques.

Comment: What version of python are you running? the `f` before the string denotes an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) and that only works with Python 3.6. Try `python -V` in the console and make sure it's 3.6 or above. if not then consider upgrading if the other dependencies will work, if not then use the old `.format` approach

Comment: This was the issue, I changed it to '%s' % (now). I believe im running 3.5.2